# Ask for a verification after a period of time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Forms app, I want to see if the user is still active. I have a form in my app that shows a random code and asks the user to enter it. How can I show this form every, let's say 10 minutes? This should work if the screen is off and the app is minimized.

Comment: when the app is backgrounded, write a timestamp to a file.  When it resumes, check the timestamp against the current time and re-validate if necessary

Comment: @Jason what if it doesn't come back in time? That doesn't seem like a reasonable method.

Comment: Combine it with a timer.  It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish - constantly nagging the user with a popup seems like a bad design.  There are other ways to track user interaction.